# Simple Field Calculation With No Results in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, concatenation

I have a grid in ArcGIS Pro that I've named the X and Y axis (in separate columns) and am now trying to do a field calculation on the total grid name (I've tried using both single and double quotes. I've tried using just a space, to test if maybe I needed an escape character):

```
!XAxis! + '-' + !YAxis!

!XAxis! + "-" + !YAxis!
```

[image]

I don't receive an error, but I don't receive any results in my table (and yes, I have refreshed multiple times and multiple minutes after running the script, knowing that sometimes there seems to be a lag in Pro)

[image]

I've used the verification at the bottom of the screen to test my syntax and it comes out clean. No errors on run, in fact, it states that it is running successfully:

[image]

I've double checked my work against Esri articles and other things I've found online... https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018207

I know that there are still a few odd bugs with Pro, but I'm hoping to find a work around (other than opening up Desktop and solving it there).

I have used a Field Calculation earlier in this exact same table to swap the X and Y axis values, when I saw that the labels did not match reality. So it's not that I don't have permissions to the table or anything like that.

All three fields I am working with (XAxis, YAxis and GridLocation) are all text fields with X & Y having field lengths of 5 (even though none are above 2 characters) and GridLocation having a field length of 15 (even though the calculation would never put the length above 11, even if both the other fields were maxed out).

Comment: Try `"{0}-{1}".format(!XAxis!,!YAxis!)`

Comment: Same results. :/

Comment: What happens if you just put a single string in, such as `'foobar'`

Comment: Also, this is a long shot but.. do you have another field with the same Alias?  It's possible to calculate a field with the field name "GridLocation" and alias "GridLocation" but be looking for the result in a field appearing to be "GridLocation" (alias) but actually be named "SomethingElse"

Comment: So, weird thing, but that field won't calculate anything. I double checked that it was not marked as read only, deleted the field and created a new one named GridLoc with same results. No, it's not aliased anywhere else. This is super bizarre to me. It was one of the last things I did before leaving yesterday and decided that my mind was fogged at the end of the day and I'd start with fresh eyes this morning. I've restarted Pro since then, since that seems to take care of a lot of the weird buggy things.

Comment: I lied. The deleting and recreating worked. It just lagged on the the refresh.

Comment: OK, glad it worked for you. The other possibility is having one row selected on accident and forgetting to hit clear.  This happens to me frequently

Comment: Yeah, I should have edited my question to add that, but nothing was selected (that was my first assumption this morning other than maybe the syntax was a bit different), I restarted pro, field was not read only, not aliased elsewhere...still no idea what caused this, but it appears to be working now. Thank you all for all of your suggestions.

Comment: I think you should self-answer based on your last few comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the field and recreating it worked for me. Never was able to get to the root of the problem, but a lot of things to look into if you run into a similar issue (see below).

Other things to attempt if you run into the same issue:

*Look to see if you have the same alias assigned to another field

*Make sure that you do not have records selected and the calculation is occurring on those rows

*Make sure the field is not read-only

*Check your permissions for the table/feature/etc

*Double check your syntax

*Fields are of the correct type and you are not trying to add an integer to a string, etc. Also, field lengths are able to handle the concatenated value.

*Restart Pro to see if you can reset whatever may be causing this

*Delete the field and re-create if all else fails